# ¿Cómo traer los datos de un campo de una base de datos MYSQL para sumarlo con el input de un usuario?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un sitio web para condominio, me encuentro atacascado en esta parte. No sé como podría afrontar esta problemática, necesito que el usuario administrador  pueda añadir deuda a los usuarios, pero si el usuario ya tiene deuda está se debe sumar con la deuda nueva.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
<html>

<head>

<?php
//Archivo de conexion 
include_once("connection.php");
session_start();

?>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <!-- Se comunica con jquery para editar la tabla -->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niramit:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&amp;subset=latin-ext,thai,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<h1>Añadir deuda al usuario</h1>

<br></br>

<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="password">Cedula del propietario</label>
  <br></br>
  <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "condotest") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users");
?>
<select name="cedula" id="cedula">
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?=$row["cedula"];?>"><?=$row["cedula"];?></option>
<?php
$i++;
}

?>
</select>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
  </div>

<br></br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="car">Coloque la nueva deuda pendiente del usuario en Bolivares</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="deuda_en_bolivares" required name="deuda_en_bolivares" min="1">
  </div>

  <br></br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Meter usuario" id="submit" name="submit">
  </div>

  <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
 $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
 $monto_deuda = $_POST['deuda_en_bolivares'];

  //esto evita que el usario meta datos en blanco
  $reqlen = strlen($cedula) + strlen($monto_deuda);

  if($reqlen > 0){
    require('connection.php'); 
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "condotest") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($db));
    $query = "SELECT * from deuda WHERE cedula_deudor = '$cedula'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if($result["cedula"]){ //Revisa si todo salio bien
      $count_query = "SELECT deuda_en_bolivares FROM deuda WHERE cedula_deudor='$cedula'";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $count_query); 
      $conteo =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
      $conteo2 = $monto_deuda + $conteo;

    }else{
    $res = "Hubo un error sumando la deuda";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$res');
      window.location.href='javascript:history.go(-1)';
    </script>";
  }


}
}
?>

 </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en connection.php, esto permite dar la conexión a la base de datos para usar los datos en ella

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "condotest";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Falló la conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>
```

Esta es la tabla a la que se debe conectar el POST para que se pueda añadir la deuda, debe sumar el campo que dice deuda_en_bolivares

```
CREATE TABLE `pagos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cedula_pago` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_pago_viejo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monto_pago` double NOT NULL,
  `monto_deuda` double NOT NULL,
  `pendiente` double NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Pero, ¿qué hace el código o donde estás atascado? Hablas de añadir deudas pero en el código no se ven consultas que añadan datos (`INSERT, UPDATE`...)

Comment: El código debe traer la deuda del usuario deacuerdo a la cedula que el administrador coloca en el input select. 

Me refiero sumar la deuda que el usuario ya tiene en la tabla de deudas con la nueva deuda que el administrador le coloca. Estoy atascado en el  $count_query = "SELECT deuda_en_bolivares FROM deuda WHERE cedula_deudor='$cedula'"; como podría sumar ese dato que se trae con el input que da el usuario

Comment: traete los datos del usuario y haces el if si el usuario tiene deuda agregas una funcion por javascript y obtienes el valor de la deuda actual y la que traes de la base de datos tienes que mandar los parametros por la funcion a javascript o jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería lo siguiente:

1. Crear un campo donde, el usuario marque si tiene deuda o no.
2. Si el usuario tiene deuda entonces agregar otra en una tabla nueva (Donde esté separado deudas de la info de usuario).
3. Solo tendrías que crear la deuda en la tabla deudas.
4. Si deseas ver todas las deudas y el total solo harías un SUM de las cantidades.

Ahora bien, si quieres llevarlo en una sola tabla... (No lo recomiendo) harías lo siguiente:

1. Verías si tiene deuda activa, si la tiene entonces cuando le des clic al botón le envías la info de la siguiente manera:

   UPDATE tabla_1 SET (campo_1 + nueva_deuda ) WHERE tabla_1.id_tabla_1 = XXXXXX;